# Reading full Names in an Archive or ISO image?

Tags: ubuntu, filenames, iso, archive

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Laptop wanting to learn Linux. I have some Video Courses in ISO Images; whenever I want to extract files from them, I don't get full names for some reason. I tried to mount it with Furuis ISO Mount Tool but got the same result.

I have to switch to Windows to extract files from the ISO image with full names.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the automatic mounts that get generated by GUI applications and they seem to take the most conservative mount options: `msdos`.

So for the moment, continue what you're doing until you come to the `mount` command in your course and then mount the ISO files manually with an `iso9660` file system and UNICODE character set like `UTF-8`.

From `man mount`:

> **iocharset=value**
>      Character set to use for converting between 8 bit characters and 16 bit Unicode characters. The default is iso8859-1. Long filenames are stored on disk in Unicode format.

If `man mount` doesn't make any sense now neither, ignore it until you reach it in your course material and then come back to this.

<sub>**Note:** Hard to remember as it was probably a long time ago, but you're a N00b again: Don't try to run before you can walk... **;-)**</sub>